# Change namespace of node libxml2

Tags: c, xml, linux, namespaces, libxml2

I want to change namespace of a node in xml.

```
doc = novi_xml_getdoc(doc_name);
if(doc==NULL){
    return -1;
}

sprintf(buff, "//%s:capable-switch",ofprefix[ofconfig_version]);
node = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context)
if(node == NULL){
    return -1;
}
xmlNsPtr ns = xmlNewNs(node,"new-namespace", "prefix");
xmlSetNs(node, ns);

xmlSaveFormatFile (doc_name, doc, 1);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
```

But this does not change the namespace of the node. The namespace remains same. I saw couple of examples, but all are related to changing namespace of childnode.

Moreover, I guess if we could modify the node by other way such as deleting and creating it again it will work. But not dont know how to link this node with its child nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The `node` result of `xmlXPathEvalExpression` isn't directly the `xmlNodePtr` you're expecting, it's an `xmlXPathObjectPtr`.

http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathObject

You'll need to drill in to `node->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]` to get the first hit of the expression.  It's also good to test `node->nodesetval` for NULL, check `node->nodesetval->nodeNr` for how many hits there are, etc.